# Datadog unable to send container logs

Tags: datadog

I am setting up datadog agent with Ansible to send docker container logs: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/basic_agent_usage/ansible/ however I notice that no logs are being sent over.

Following: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/log-collection-troubleshooting-guide/ I've tried to first send a test message with `openssl s_client -connect intake.logs.datadoghq.com:10516` and then `<API_KEY> this is a test message` which outputs nothing and I notice that no logs are sent with a "closed". If I check `/var/log/datadog/agent.log` I do not see any errors listing 10516.

If I check status: `sudo datadog-agent status`

```
===============
Agent (v7.38.1)
===============
...
  Paths
  =====
    Config File: /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml
    conf.d: /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d
    checks.d: /etc/datadog-agent/checks.d
...
==========
Logs Agent
==========
    Reliable: Sending compressed logs in HTTPS to agent-http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com on port 443
    BytesSent: 0
    EncodedBytesSent: 0
    LogsProcessed: 0
    LogsSent: 0

  container_collect_all
  ---------------------
    - Type: docker
      Status: Pending
      BytesRead: 0
      Average Latency (ms): 0
      24h Average Latency (ms): 0
      Peak Latency (ms): 0
      24h Peak Latency (ms): 0
```

But I do not see any explanation as to why docker log collection is pending. I have also done a chmod 745 on `/var/lib/docker/` and 744 on `/var/lib/docker/containers`.

Checking for errors `sudo cat /var/log/datadog/agent.log | grep ERROR`:
`(pkg/forwarder/worker.go:184 in process) | Error while processing transaction: error while sending transaction, rescheduling it: Post "https://7-38-1-app.agent.datadoghq.com/api/v1/series?api_key=<api_key>": dial tcp [2600:1f18:24e6:b901:1af8:1d45:efec:931d]:443: connect: network is unreachable`

I couldn't find an explaination here as to why network is unreachable however.

The API_KEY is valid as it is uploading other metrics to our dashboard, however I see no docker container logs.

My ansible configuration is:

```
    - role: datadog.datadog
      become: true
      vars:
        datadog_api_key: "{{ logs_datadog_api_key }}"
        #datadog_site: "datadoghq.com"
        datadog_config:
          tags:
            - "env:{{ datadog_environment }}"
            # tags
          log_level: INFO
          logs_config:
            container_collect_all: true
            use_http: true
          apm_config:
            enabled: true
          logs_enabled: true
        network_config:
          enabled: true
```

I've also tried setting use_http to true but still nothing is sent. Is there something that I am missing, or doing wrong? Should I just run datadog agent as a containerized instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I couldn't find why the port was not able to opened and why container logs were stuck in pending. I did update my local configuration to:

```
- name: Install docker python package
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: docker

- name: Pull Datadog agent image
  community.docker.docker_image:
    name: "datadog/agent"
    tag: "latest"
    source: pull

- name: Get current agent container
  docker_container_info:
    name: "dd_agent"
  register: result

- name: Stop agent container if running
  docker_container:
    name: "dd_agent"
    state: stopped
  when: result is defined and result.exists

- name: Remove agent container if running
  docker_container:
    name: "dd_agent"
    state: absent
  when: result is defined and result.exists

- name: Run Datadog agent container
  docker_container:
    env:
      DD_API_KEY: "{{ api_key }}"
      DD_LOGS_ENABLED: "true"
      DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL: "true"
      DD_HOSTNAME: "{{ host }}"
      DD_APM_ENABLED: "false"
      DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC: "false"
      DD_PROCESS_AGENT_ENABLED: "true"
      DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE: "name:datadog-agent"
    image: "datadog/agent:latest"
    name: "dd_agent"
    restart_policy: "unless-stopped"
    state: started
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /proc/:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - /opt/datadog-agent/logs:/opt/datadog-agent/run:rw
```

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal solution but you can enable sending them through HTTP by setting environment var DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP=true